# Bilanz ziehen/erstellen/machen

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

I have heard the following sentence in [ZDF news](https://www.zdf.de/nachrichten-sendungen/heute-journal/heute-journal-vom-19-maerz-2024-100.html#showSubtitles=true):

> Heute zieht die Weltorganisation für Meteorologie eine düstere Bilanz

If I understood correctly, "ziehen" here means the creation of the balance/report and its sharing with the world. Would there be any difference in meaning if "erstellen" or "machen" was used instead? If no, are those 3 verbs equally usual in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning is different. The phrase "eine Bilanz erstellen" is a term from accounting and means to create a balance sheet for a business with assets and liabilities. It is something that businesses have to do for each year, and among other things it shows the result of the year in terms of profit or loss. If you say "eine Bilanz machen", it would probably be understood to mean create (erstellen), but it sounds strange.

Now "Bilanz ziehen", usually without "eine", is a [fixed phrase](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Bilanz%20ziehen) with a figurative meaning. People not familiar with accounting vaguely remember that "Bilanz" has something to do with a result, and use it to refer to any result. At least they use a different verb, so that it is obvious that it probably means something else. Of course it is not related to pulling (ziehen), but it might be related to the fact that "ziehen" is also used for "Schlussfolgerungen" (conclusions).

In the article, they don't talk about a balance, they probably don't even know what the word means, they talk about a report. The phrase "Bilanz ziehen" doesn't imply sharing the report with the world, but obviously in that case you wouldn't know about it. It might also be used for an internal report within an organization or group.

Answer (score 0):

„Bilanz ziehen“ is a fixed phrase meaning *to take stock*. You can't exchange its verb.

Comment: In case someone is not familiar with the English fixed phrase, it means "to think carefully about a situation or event and form an opinion about it, so that you can decide what to do". Reference: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-stock

Comment: ...in other words, if you say "Bilanz erstellen", the meaning of Bilanz is different and it is the literal sense: "prepare the balance sheets". In contrast, "Bilanz ziehen" has a figurative meaning. The verb is the same as in "einen Schluss ziehen" = "*draw* a conclusion", maybe because the meanings of the phrases are analogous.